# dnsmasq fails to resolve queries and restart after sleep mode

Tags: domain-name-system, systemd, dnsmasq

i'm yet another user trying to unwrap systemd-resolved, NetowrkManager and dnsmasq horror with addition of proprietary vpn that messes with /etc/resolve.conf.

I want to have dnsmasq as my only resolver. So i've turned off both systemd-resolved and NetworkManager's dns configuration:

```
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

```
# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.

[main]
dns = none
```

dnsmasq is obviously enabled in systemd:

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```

The problem is that dnsmasq works only up to the moment when i put my laptop to sleep. After that dnsmasq process is still present in process list, all the queries time out (i'm not sure whether dnsmasq accepting them at all), and it can't be restarted before full reboot for reason i can't understand:

```
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: Stopped dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint dnsmasq[9896]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint dnsmasq[9897]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Cannot assign requested address
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint dnsmasq[9897]: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Cannot assign requested address
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint dnsmasq[9897]: FAILED to start up
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: Stopped dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 10:59:05 varmint systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

According to netstat and ss, there is nothing listening on 127.0.0.1:53, which is expected since dnsmasq process isn't running at this moment. I can't find anything else related in journalctl output. I see the same behavior if i switch to NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq.

update: i tried bind just to see whether problem is wider than just dnsmasq. here's what i see after wakeup:

```
Sep 27 12:16:44 varmint named[6605]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Sep 27 12:16:44 varmint named[6605]: no longer listening on ::1#53
```

guess that may be key to everything

What is wrong? How can i debug this? Had anyone seen something like that and have any clues?

Some additional info:

Operating system: Manjaro 20 KDE
Kernel: 5.8.6-1-MANJARO
dnsmasq installed as official package 2.82-2
dnsmasq systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Documentation=man:dnsmasq(8)
After=network.target
Before=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/dnsmasq --test
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dnsmasq -k --enable-dbus --user=dnsmasq --pid-file
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
PrivateDevices=true
ProtectSystem=full

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was self-induced hell. The whole setup is needed just to work with some environment,requiring catching special names and resolving them into predefined local addresses in 172, which also have to be bound by hand. The latter was done through systemd-networkd via custom file in `/etc/systemd/network/`; after deleting it everything start working normal.